# How can you stream a multipart request body with Koa?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, multipartform-data, koa

I am developing a web app and would like to stream file uploads straight to S3 (or Minio in my development environment). It doesn't look like `koa-better-body` or `koa-body` can stream, what might be a way I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the original request in the context via `ctx.request.req`: https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/lib/application.js#L153

With this you should be able to use express tools for what you need.